# Is there an opposite method for .charAt()?

Tags: java, methods

The remove.charAt() does not seem to work so I was wondering if there was something, where I input an int and it tells me what character is at that point?
Again if anyone has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated. :-)

```
public static String removeYak(String remove)
{
    String fina1 = "";
    for(int y = 0; y < remove.length(); y++)
    {
        if(remove.toLowerCase().charAt(y) == "y")
        {
            if(remove.toLowerCase().charAt(y+1) == "a")
            {
                if(remove.toLowerCase().charAt(y+2) == "k")
                {
                    fina1 = str.substring(k+1);

                }
            }
        }
    }
    return fina1;
}
```

Comment: Your title and actual question don't line up. What are you trying to accomplish and what's your question?

Comment: This is supposed to remove yak from a String ex.) "yakpak"

Comment: Also - `charAt` returns a char. You have to compare with a *char* literal, not a String literal...

Comment: What the heck is `k`?

Comment: Wait never mind I just realized the answer is right under my nose, 'if(remove.toLowerCase().substring(y+1,y+2)  == "a")'. Whoops, sorry guys...

Comment: And you call `toLowerCase()` potentially hundreds of times. Just remember `String lower = remove.toLowerCase();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't. However, you're using a correct method. The problem is in your if's. When you do something like:

```
String string = "abc";
char c = string.charAt(2);
```

You must compare character to a character, not to a string. In your if's, you write things like `remove.toLowerCase().charAt(y) == "y"`, however, what you're looking for is `remove.toLowerCase().charAt(y) == 'y'`. Notice the apostrophe by the y you must use.

Comment: Thanks, that added a whole different perspective to what I was doing. Thanks for the help!